# Dynamic selects on iPhone not working

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have two select elements. Making a choice on the first select will build the options for the second select.  Works fine on desktop browsers.

On the iPhone, after you make your choice on the first one and chose "Next", the options do not get filled in the second select. So far, the only ways to do this is to go from the second select, back to the "Previous" one and then back, "Next" to the second select. The other way to click "Done" and then tap the second select.

I've tried both .change() and .click() and both produce the same results.

Below is the JS and here is a working example http://damonomania.com/select/

Any suggestions? TIA!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#select-1').change(function() {
        show_options();
    });

    function show_options() {
        var id = $('#select-1').val();
        $('#select-2 option:gt(0)').remove();
        $.each(options[id], function(k,v) {
            $('#select-2').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>');
        });
    }
});

var options = {"17":{"835":"870","836":"871"},"18":{"435":"870","436":"871"},"13":{"1":"123546"},"19":{"1213":"4010","1206":"4015"}}
```

Comment: Just tried it on my iPhone 4G and it seemed to work fine. Everytime I changed the first one the second one had new values.

Comment: @spinon Can you try again. I updated the dynamic selects to have some meaning relative to the first select. So if "Something 2" is selected the new values should be "From 2a, From 2b", etc. That way you should be able to tell if they are not from a previous stale selection.

Thanks.

Comment: Ugh! Thanks spinon. I don't want this to be a "just me" problem. I'm on a 3G running 4.0. Can anyone else give this a try on other models as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on my site. I was able to fix it by manually polling the `selectedIndex` property on the select control. That way it fires as soon as you "check" the item in the list. Here's a jQuery plugin I wrote to do this:

```
$.fn.quickChange = function(handler) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var self = this;
        self.qcindex = self.selectedIndex;
        var interval;
        function handleChange() {
            if (self.selectedIndex != self.qcindex) {
                self.qcindex = self.selectedIndex;
                handler.apply(self);
            }
        }
        $(self).focus(function() {
            interval = setInterval(handleChange, 100);
        }).blur(function() { window.clearInterval(interval); })
        .change(handleChange); //also wire the change event in case the interval technique isn't supported (chrome on android)
    });
};
```

You use it just like you would use the "change" event. For instance:

```
$("#mySelect1").quickChange(function() { 
    var currVal = $(this).val();
    //populate mySelect2
});
```

**Edit**: Android does not focus the select when you tap it to select a new value, but it also does not have the same problem that iphone does. So fix it by also wiring the old `change` event.

Comment: I just quickly tested this out and was happy to find that it works on iOS 4! Thanks for sharing. I'll be using this a lot!