# jQuery refresh dropdown

Tags: asp.net, jquery, telerik

I followed the examples to update a dropdown from the selection of another dropdown:

```
    var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Reports.aspx")%>';
    function PopulatePortfolioDropDown() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=ddlPortfolio.ClientID %>');
        ddl.options.length = 0;
        var prgyr = document.getElementById('<%= ddlProgYear.ClientID %>');
        var agy = document.getElementById('<%= ddlAgency.ClientID %>');
        $telerik.$('#<%=ddlPortfolio.ClientID %>').empty(); //.append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please Select...</option>');
        var str = prgyr.options[prgyr.selectedIndex].text + '|' + agy.options[agy.selectedIndex].value;
        $telerik.$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + '/LoadPortfolioDDL1',
            data: '{yearcode:"' + str + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnPortfolioData,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            } 
        });
    }
    function OnPortfolioData(response) {
        PopulateControl(response.d, $telerik.$('#<%=ddlPortfolio.ClientID %>'));
    }
    function PopulateControl(list, control) {
         if (list.length > 0) {
            control.attr("disabled", false);
            control.empty();
            $telerik.$.each(list, function () {
                control.append($telerik.$("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        }
        else {
            control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Not available<option>');
        }
    }
```

This works great when ddlAgency is first selected.  If I make a second selection the displayed list is not updated and the original list is still displayed.  However, if I select one of the items in the second list, the updated item (from the second call) is shown correctly.  Is this a problem with IE?  A little more info:  the DDL I want to update is not populated with any data upon page load.  If I select the DDL, it will not show any options.  Even after I make a selection in the controlling DDL the second shows no items.  If I do not click on the DDL, the items show up.  It's like the DDL will keep what it had the first time it is clicked on.  Does this make sense?  What the heck is causing this?  I know the data is being cleared and new options added but the page still shows the old list or none at all.

Comment: Please can you post the code that you use to update a dropdown from another?

Comment: Simple: when ddlAgency changes (onchange event) it calls PopulatePortfolioDropDown() which is supposed to update ddlPortfolio.  It's like when ddlPortfolio gets the focus, it doesn't update.

Answer (score 1):

To update select menus, jquery has a basic .change function which listens for when an option is select.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

However, if you want the change to be dynamic, this .quickchange workaround is the charmer you need:

[Dynamic selects on iPhone not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169349/dynamic-selects-on-iphone-not-working)

You are simply appending elements but not updating the select list to reflect the change when an option is selected.

Here is an example on the selected attribute:

[JQuery setting the selected attribute on a select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311287/jquery-setting-the-selected-attribute-on-a-select-list)